# issue on jfrog integration with azure devops maven

Tags: azure-devops, azure-pipelines, artifactory

[image]

after integration with azure devops,jfrog shows error like this, please see above snip for your reference.

Comment: It seems like the Azure DevOps could not find the path and failed to publish. The path is very clear here in the screenshot. Can you check if this path is available and can be accessed? Like have the right permissions?

Comment: Hi kalyan, and welcome to Stack Overflow. Can I make a suggestion about your question? It would be improved if you edit it to include all the information in text format, rather than in an image. It helps for indexing and readability, for example.

Comment: [Please don't post screenshots of text](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/285557/354577). They can't be searched or copied, or even consumed by users of adaptive technologies like screen readers. Instead, paste the code as text directly into your question. If you select it and click the `{}` button or Ctrl+K the code block will be indented by four spaces, which will cause it to be rendered as code.